No new random number generated
I made a teddybaer with buttons, LEDs, and voice output for my son. There are some buttons with pictures of our family with LEDs behind. The adruino is connected to a DfPlayer mini.
After pressing a button (picture) the LED behind gets illuminated and a random track corresponding to the picture will be played.
That´s all no problem and worked good...
But it was a bit boring, being not able to switch a track before it was terminated. So, I outcommented this:
void MP3Player::playTrackNumber(int trackNumber, int volume, boolean waitPlayTerminated)
    {
        player.volume(volume);
        player.play(trackNumber);
        if (waitPlayTerminated)
        {
        
        //    waitPlayIsTerminated();
        }
    }

Now, it was possible to press another button and a random track corresponding to that button was played.
If I press the same button again, the same track plays every time.
#include "mp3tf16p.h"

long randNumber;
long randNumber2;
long randNumber3;
long randNumber4;
long randNumber5;

MP3Player mp3(2, 3 );

//marina
const int button1 = 4;
//micha
const int button2 = 6;
//mama
const int button3 = 8;
//galina
const int button4 = 10;
//alex
const int button5 = 12;
//marina
const int led1 = 5;
//MICHA
const int led2 = 7;
//mama
const int led3 = 9;
//galina
const int led4 = 11;
//alex
const int led5 = 13;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(LED_BUILTIN , OUTPUT);

mp3.initialize();

 randomSeed(analogRead(A0) * analogRead(A1));

pinMode (button1,INPUT);
pinMode (button2,INPUT); 
pinMode (button3,INPUT);
pinMode (button4,INPUT);
pinMode (button5,INPUT);

pinMode (led1, OUTPUT);
pinMode (led2, OUTPUT);
pinMode (led3, OUTPUT);
pinMode (led4, OUTPUT);
pinMode (led5, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
int reads = digitalRead(button1);
int reads2 = digitalRead(button2);
int reads3 = digitalRead(button3);
int reads4 = digitalRead(button4);
int reads5 = digitalRead(button5);




 randomSeed(analogRead(A0) * analogRead(A1));

// mp3.playTrackNumber(15, 30);  
//marina
if (reads==1)
{

   randomSeed(analogRead(A0) * analogRead(A1));
  randNumber = random(1, 7);
   
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);


 //  mp3.playTrackNumber(30, 30);  

  if (randNumber==1)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(12, 30);  
  }
  
    if (randNumber==2)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(13, 30);  
  }
  if (randNumber==3)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(14, 30);  
  }

  if (randNumber==4)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(16, 30);  
  }
if (randNumber==5)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(17, 30);  
  }

if (randNumber==6)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(18, 30);  
  }
  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
}
else {

}

//micha
if (reads2==1)
{

  
   randomSeed(analogRead(A0) * analogRead(A1));
  randNumber2 = random(1, 7);
   randomSeed(analogRead(A0) * analogRead(A1));

  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);

  if (randNumber2==1)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(2, 30);  
  }
  
    if (randNumber2==2)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(3, 30);  
  }
  if (randNumber2==3)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(4, 30);  
  }

 if (randNumber2==4)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(10, 30);  
  }

   if (randNumber2==5)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(11, 30);  
  }

   if (randNumber2==6)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(6, 30);  
  }

  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
}
else {

}
//Alexander
if (reads5==1)
{
 // mp3.playTrackNumber(6, 30); 
  randomSeed(analogRead(A0) * analogRead(A1));
  randNumber3 = random(1, 10);
  randomSeed(analogRead(A0) * analogRead(A1));
  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);

  if (randNumber3==1)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(6, 30);  
  }
  
    if (randNumber3==2)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(5, 30);  
  }
  if (randNumber3==3)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(6, 30);  
  }
  

 if (randNumber3==4)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(7, 30);  
  }

   if (randNumber3==5)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(8, 30);  
  
}
  if (randNumber3==6)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(9, 30);  
  
}
 if (randNumber3==7)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(15, 30);  
  
}

 if (randNumber3==8)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(20, 30);  
  
}

 if (randNumber3==9)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(21, 30);  
  
}
digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
}
else {

}


//galina
if (reads4==1)
{
   randomSeed(analogRead(A0) * analogRead(A1));
  randNumber4 = random(2, 9);
//  randomSeed(analogRead(A0) * analogRead(A1));
  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
if (randNumber4==2)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(19, 30);  
  
}
if (randNumber4==3)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(24, 30);  
  
}
if (randNumber4==4)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(25, 30);  
  
}
if (randNumber4==5)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(26, 30);  
  
}
if (randNumber4==6)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(27, 30);  
  
}
if (randNumber4==7)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(28, 30);  
  }

if (randNumber4==8)
  {
  mp3.playTrackNumber(29, 30);  
  

}
  digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
}
if (reads3==1)
{
    randomSeed(analogRead(A0) * analogRead(A1));
  randNumber5 = random(1, 8);
  randomSeed(analogRead(A0) * analogRead(A1));
  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    mp3.playTrackNumber(22, 30); 
}
else {

}
digitalWrite(led3, LOW);

mp3.serialPrintStatus(MP3_ALL_MESSAGE);


}

Why is it possible in case I press another button while a track is played, that it plays randomly. But if I press the same button again which is already played, the same track will start new as if the program just starts the track new but without generating a new random number?

Where is the rest of the code?

I would put the random seed into setup and not in your main loop. Other than that, maybe there is a bug in the part of the code you haven't shown.

Sorry, I posted all the code, now.

Why do you keep reseeding the random.number generator.  You need that once in setup.

It´s solved, now. You are right, with randomseed in setup only it works perfectly. Would be better to understand an instruction before using it. Thank you!

your code is overly repetitive .... use arrays to define variables ... for example define const int track[] = {6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 20, 21}; then play tracks without the need for if statements, mp3.playTrackNumber(track[random], 30);

you could also define the list of tracks in a 2D array, and then have only one play statement in the whole program mp3.playTrackNumber(track[button][random], 30);

Stop reseeding the random number generator!
You are supposed to seed it once, (in setup). If you reseed it with the same seed, you will get the same number every time.
I would be a bit surprised if the analogRead gave the same result every time, but say A0 returned zero because that pin was grounded then zero times any number will be zero, so you will always seed the random number generator with zero, and the random number you ask for will always be the same.
Also, try to do a bit of arithmetic. Instead of:
 if (randNumber == 1)
    {
      mp3.playTrackNumber(12, 30);
    }

    if (randNumber == 2)
    {
      mp3.playTrackNumber(13, 30);
    }
    if (randNumber == 3)
    {
      mp3.playTrackNumber(14, 30);
    }

    if (randNumber == 4)
    {
      mp3.playTrackNumber(16, 30);
    }
    if (randNumber == 5)
    {
      mp3.playTrackNumber(17, 30);
    }

    if (randNumber == 6)
    {
      mp3.playTrackNumber(18, 30);
    }

How about:
      mp3.playTrackNumber(11 + randNumber, 30);

That's a lot shorter don't you think? Or if that doesn't work for you (I didn't skip track 15 like you did), you can read up on how case statements work.

I didn´t understood how randomseed works and thought I must use it again to get a different number. I put it in setup only and now everything works perfectly! :-)

Thank you very much and thanks for the other hints, too!
